# How to host a sample applink json file into a sample website?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Any one suggest to host a instant app related json into the following

sample website

https://sample.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Since we dont have separate domain server for this, so any way is there to put the json file into a created website.

Comment: would firebase static hosting work for you?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "created website". The assetlinks json file must be on the same domain as the URLs declared for your Instant App.

Comment: Currently don't have any website created. how to put json into that .well-known folder.

Comment: check out this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at StackOverflow's own `assetlinks.json` [file here](https://stackoverflow.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json).

Android Studio has a [generator & validity checker](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html) for this file, too.

Answer (score 0):

> Since we don't have separate domain server for this, so any way is
> there to put the json file into a created website

> Currently I don't have any website created. how to put json into that
> .well-known folder. –

This is not possible you must have ownership of the site allowing access to GoogleBot into the https://sample.name/robot.txt defining:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /.well-known/
```

the configure your assetlinks.json file:

https://sample.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json